# JQuery MVC - Masked Textbox that accepts both letters and numbers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, maskedtextbox

So, I have my regular Textbox but I can't seem to find a mask that accepts alphanumeric values.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">                   
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Security code:</label>      
        @Html.TextBox("txtSecCode", null, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 20 })
    </div>                    
</div>
```

**Javascript:** (btw I'm using the razer engine view)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#txtSecCode').keyup(function () {
            // I used this to not let the user input any special characters.
            if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
            }
        });

        // The 'blur' function is used to auto-mask the field when it's not focused
        $('#txtSecCode').blur(function () {
            // So that's my mask, at first my field's maxlength was set to 
            // 16, but than some errors occured and then I realized that the 
            // dots(.) of the mask were the guilt for this.
            $('#txtSecCode').mask('9999.9999.9999.9999'); 
        });                                                     
    });
</script>
```

Anyway, the mask should accept values like: *'98AC.981X.B8TZ.EW89'*.
If anyone knows about a textbox field mask that allows me to enter alphanumeric values, please let me know.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will match only numbers, letters, and the `.`.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.]
```

As far as your general approach though, I think you could accomplish the same thing more concisely by doing HTML5 validation.  With the `pattern` attribute you can specify regex right on the input element like this:

```
<input required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.]+">
```

I see you're using an MVC helper in razor to create your elements...I believe you can just change your 4th line to this and take out the js:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtSecCode", null, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 20,  required = "required", pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9.]+"})
```

It doesn't really matter what you set `required` to, just that you set it to something to make sure the property gets included.